# How to check if a given window is open in Xul?

Tags: xul

How to check if a given window is open in Xul?

I would like to check if a window is already openned in my desktop app. So if it is, I'll not open it again.

**-- my attempt**

I'm trying to accomplish this using the window title, so I get the list of windows from `windowManager` and check the title, but the `getAttribute` is not from an interface that I can query, it's from [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element), what interface should I use?

```
var windowManager = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
var enum = windowManager.getXULWindowEnumerator(null);
while(enum.hasMoreElements()) {
    var win = enum.getNext().QueryInterface(Components.interfaces[" WHICH INTERFACE TO PUT HERE? "]);
    write("WINDOW TITLE = " + win.getAttribute("title"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var windowManager = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
var enum = windowManager.getEnumerator(null);
while(enum.hasMoreElements()) {
  var win = enum.getNext().QueryInterface( Components.interfaces.nsIDOMChromeWindow );
  write("WINDOW TITLE = " + win.document.documentElement.getAttribute("title") );
}
```

if you are using getXULWindowEnumerator you should use Components.interfaces.nsIXULWindow

you probably could use the nsIDOMWindow attribute name if you open the windows your self because you set the name of the window in the open function. This is not visible to the user so you have a little more flexibility

```
var win = window.open( "chrome://myextension/content/about.xul", 
                          "windowName", "chrome,centerscreen" );

write( "WINDOW NAME: " + win.name ); // Should now give  WINDOW NAME: windowName
```

If you are leaving the window name blank it will open a new window every time. If you however use a window name (something else than "" ) it will create it if it does not exists, or load the new content in the already existing window with the name you have specified.

Which seems like almost what you want. Butt you could use name attribute to avoid the reload if you have to.

```
var openNewWindow = true;
var windowManager = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
var enum = windowManager.getEnumerator(null);

while(enum.hasMoreElements()) {
  var win = enum.getNext().QueryInterface( Components.interfaces.nsIDOMChromeWindow );
  if( win.name == "windowName" ) {
    openNewWindow = false;
  }
}

if( openNewWindow ) {
  var win = window.open( "chrome://myextension/content/about.xul", 
                      "windowName", "chrome" );
}
```

Comment: With the first approach (getEnumerator and nsIDomChromeWindow) it shows the windows, but on the second time, after open a new window, didn't show the new window I opened using window.open(). With getXULWindowEnumerator and nsIXULWindow it says that `win.document is undefined`.

Comment: @TomBrito the nsIXULWindow interface looks like this [link](http://www.oxymoronical.com/experiments/apidocs/platform/1.9.2a1pre/interface/nsIXULWindow) and dont have a document attribute. Butt check out my update

Comment: @TomBrito then I dont get what the problem is anymore? If you want to open several windows from the same xul file you need to use a blank window name otherwise it will only refresh the already open window with the same name

Comment: @LeadingLight I'm not leaving window name blank. The result for win.name using your last approach is always 'undefined'. I'm using WMaker as Window Manager, maybe it makes some difference.. I'll search for something about..

Comment: @TomBrito aha okej. Butt you are abel to get the title? So it would be possible to try you first approach checking the window title?

Comment: @LeadingLight it gives `null` for some, and nothing (empty string) for others

Comment: @LeadingLight ops, I was getting the name attribute from the documment.. It works better if I get if from the window =D

Answer (score 3):

If you set a `windowtype="myWindowType"` attribute on your document's `<window>` element then you can just use `windowMediator.getMostRecentWindow('myWindowType');` to see whether you already have one open.